# how to get an integer from the current year in Microsoft access

Tags: ms-access

I want to get the current year and minus it from another year and have the result be an integer.

To do this, do I have to use a calculated column and what code would I have to use.

I have tried things such as Date() however it always tells me that I cannot use it in a calculated column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That could be this expression in a query:

```
YearDiff: [OtherYear]-Year(Date())
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to add it as a calculated field, since as the question stated, you can't use `Date` in a calculated field. Of course, having calculated fields that depend on the current date is a dubious premise knowing how calculated fields work in Access. The better answer is "don't do calculated fields, do queries instead"

Comment: @ErikA: Yes. I read it as it is about a calculation/expression in a query.